# Get space after certain pattern

Tags: python

I have input file as

```
cellabc
A1
A2
Z
cellbpc
A1
A2
A3
Z
```

I want my output as

```
module cell abc
A1
A2
Z
module cell bpc
A1
A2
A3
Z
```

I tried code

```
for line in f:
re.sub(r'(cell)',r'\1 ',line)
```

Here I first tried to get space after cell word. But unable to get. Please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```py
for line in f:
    sub = re.sub('cell', 'module cell ', line)
```

`re.sub` takes three obligatory arguments:

```py
re.sub(pattern, repl, string)
```

Where the pattern is what you're looking for, the replacement of the string, and string that remains when the found pattern is removed.

```
module cell abc
A1
A2
Z
module cell bpc
A1
A2
A3
Z
```

Comment: I am not getting output with this probably because I have no word exact matching to cell so unable to replace it.

Comment: So your file doesn't look like the lines you showed in the first part of your question?

Comment: The data which I showed in the first part is correct. But using this I am unable  to get as its matching cell but in file we have cellabc.

Comment: `re.sub()` is going to look for the string that you pass in for the argument `pattern`. So, even if you have lines that look like "cellabc", it will detect "cell" in that line.